# Esper How to express dependecies between sentences

Tags: esper

I'm a novice in using the Esper event stream engine in Java. 
I want to detect some alerts in the folowing way
If condition-A then Alert-A
If condition-B then Alert-B
If condition-C and (not Alert-A and not Alert-B) then Alert-C
The conditions are not exclusives.
In the scenario of temperatures will be to to test if the temperature > 50, 100, 150 for example (my scenario is more complex)
I don’t know how to solve this problem.
I have tried with @priority and @drop, but without success (I think that the engine doesn’t take into account) I have put 
config.getEngineDefaults().getExecution().setPrioritized(true);
And the EPL sentences are:

```
@Name('critical') 
@Drop  
@Priority(9) 
Insert into AlertEvent 
select *, 'critical' as type 
from TemperatureEvent (reading > 100)
@Name('warning') 
Insert into AlertEvent 
select *, 'warning' as type from TemperatureEvent (reading > 200)
```

Any temperature event classified as 'warning', it is also classified as ‘critical’. 
Any way, I would prefer a solution without priority and drop,
Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Esper has a splitting and duplicating syntax that provides a convenient way. Its described in [1]. I have not tested the below for you but it should be close:

```
on TemperatureEvent(reading > 100)
insert into AlertEvent select ... where reading > 200
insert into AlertEvent select ...
```

[1] http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.0.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#split_overview

Comment: What happens when de condition is more complex like a pattern?